# Create a server control from code behind using literalcontrol

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm actually trying to create a `Panel` from codebehind with some server control inside, to do that I'm using a `LiteralControl` but the `LiteralControl` does not work with server control and that is what I need in this case. How can I do this. Please help.

I have something like this:

```
Panel pnl = new Panel();

pnl.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<label>SomeBanner: </label>"));

pnl.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<asp:TextBox ID='TextBox1' runat='server' Width='65px'/>"));
```

As I said, the first add (label) works perfectly but the second add does not works because I'm trying to create a server control using the LiteralControl which does not support this action.

How can I do this or what is the best practice in this case?

Comment: You can not to create controls in this way.

Answer (score 4):

The purpose of the `LiteralControl` is to send literal HTML to the client. Rather, you're looking to add a [`TextBox`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox(v=vs.110).aspx) control to the `Panel`.

```
Panel pnl = new Panel();
pnl.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<label>SomeBanner: </label>"));

TextBox tb = new TextBox();
tb.ID = "TextBox1";
pnl.Controls.Add(tb);
```

While you're at it, I'd be tempted to use the [`Label`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.label(v=vs.110).aspx) control for your "SomeBanner" text. That would let you associate the `Label` and the `Textbox` ([`Label.AssociatedControlID`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.label.associatedcontrolid(v=vs.110).aspx)), which has some advantages for end-user usability.

Comment: Thanks @Matthew Hougen, I know this way you specified here but what I need is to send the HTML code via c# to create the server control.

Comment: @Poyson1 you can't send a client HTML that creates a server control, by definition. What result are you hoping to get? And while we're at it, how does the result of this code vary from your desired result?

Comment: Look, what I'm doing is creating a ToolBar with some custom server controls such as 'date from-date to', pint, export to pdf and so on, then to create the datetimepiker I'm using a third party controlfrom OboutInc (Calendar) but they don't permit to creat an instance of one of their objets but only paste the control on the html. I had already finished if they let me do an instance like class obj = new class, but they don't.

Comment: Hi again @Matthew Hougen, look, finally in the toolbar I'm creating I need a calendar into a textbox just like this http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/act_calendar.ashx but I need to do it from code behind NOT pasting the control on the html source.